# How to configure apache to serve multiple tomcat apps as subdomains

Tags: java, apache, .htaccess, tomcat, subdomain

I am trying to accomplish the following behavior:

```
user1.mydomain.com -> redirected to /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/user1/
user2.mydomain.com -> redirected to /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/user2/
```

As I add new applications to Tomcat's webapps folder, I want them to be automatically available using the same subdomain pattern.

With the configurations below, right now, when accessing `user2.mydomain.com:8010` I get the 'It works!' page from apache. However accessing `user2.mydomain.com:8010/user2` works just fine.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong but I cannot figure out what. Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

I'm using apache in front of tomcat with mod_jk connector for url rewriting.

subdomain configuration:

```
* IN CNAME mydomain.com.
www.* IN CNAME mydomain.com.
```

.htaccess in /var/www:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?user1.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !user1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user1/$1 [L]
```

000-default configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled:

```
<VirtualHost *:8010>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

JkMount /* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

workers.properties:

```
#Define 1 real worker using ajp13
worker.list=worker1
#Set properties for worker (ajp13)
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to do the virtual-host mapping in the tomcat itself and place your apps as "ROOT" application under different hosts.

E.g define following in the server.xml:

```
<Host name="user1.mydomain.com" appBase="user1"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" 
    xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false" />

<Host name="user2.mydomain.com" appBase="user2"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" 
    xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false" />
```

Then create 2 folders:

```
.../tomcat/user1/
.../tomcat/user2/
```

and deploy your applications as "ROOT" under them.

Comment: But this would require a server restart each time a new application is being deployed, right? I would like to be able to add as many applications as needed at runtime without restarting the server.

Comment: Note that each deployed application will take memory so your scaling is very limited in any way. If you need scaling, you should design your tomcat application in a way that single instance may deal with "userX/" paths or "userX.mydomoain.com" hosts on its own.